# command line input directory read with tab autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, input, sh

I need for user to point out a directory path in command line but when trying to suggest folders with  tab it gives me tab spaces

```
function selectFolder() {
  local dir
  read -p "Enter the path of the dir : "  dir

  cd "$dir"  || {
    exit 0
  }
  local dir=$(pwd)
  cd - > /dev/null 2>&1
  echo "$dir"
}
```

Can't find a clue so far please help

Comment: you need to add ```-e``` to ```read```

Comment: 10x @bac0n appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer of the working function for those who face the same problem

```
function selectFolder() {
  local dir
  read -ep "Enter the path of the dir : "  dir

  {
    cd "$dir"
  } || {
    exit 0
  }
  local dir=$(pwd)
  cd - > /dev/null 2>&1
  echo "$dir"
}

# invoke function
selectFolder
```